# How to filter a list of dictionaries by checking if another list of words are existed in those dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, filter

Hi I have a list of dictionaries where I want to check if any of these dictionaries contain a specific words from a list of words, I want to match the exact word
for example I want to match the word 'bad' if there was a word called 'baddest' I don't wanna it to be included, that's why I'm using regular expressions
here, I have already achieved that but I'm just wondering if there is a better and a more readable way to do that.

here is my code:

```
import re


words = ['bad', 'sad']


books = [

 {
    'title': 'bad book',
    'description': 'this book contains bad text'
},

{
    'title': 'book two',
    'description': 'this book also contains Bad text'
},

{
    'title': 'good book',
    'description': 'this book will help you to overcome baddest habits'
},
{

    'title': 'book four',
    'description': 'this book is about a sad story'
}
 ]


 def filter_books(book):

    if not any(re.search(rf'\b{word}\b', book['title'], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
           or re.search(rf'\b{word}\b', book['description'], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
           for word in words):
      return True

  return False


  good_books = list(filter(filter_books, books))


  print(good_books)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

words = ['bad', 'sad']

books = [

    {
        'title': 'bad book',
        'description': 'this book contains bad text'
    },

    {
        'title': 'book two',
        'description': 'this book also contains Bad text'
    },

    {
        'title': 'good book',
        'description': 'this book will help you to overcome baddest habits'
    },
    {

        'title': 'book four',
        'description': 'this book is about a sad story'
    }
]


def is_word_present(word):
    for w in words:
        if (re.search(rf'\b{w}\b', word, flags=re.IGNORECASE)):
            return True
    return False


def _filter(books):
    res = []
    for book in books:
        if is_word_present(book['title']) or is_word_present(book['description']):
            pass
        else:
            res.append(book)
    return res


good_books = _filter(books)
print(good_books)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
def filter(book):
    result = False
    all = book['title'] + ' ' + book['description']
    for item in words:
        if item in re.split(pattern='.| |,|;', string=all):
            result = True
    return result
```

This checks if one of the words in your `words` list is in the title or in the description. One bad thing: this is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of ways,

```
# using set data-structure

words = {'bad', 'sad'}

# 6.99 µs ± 426 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
print([
    book for book in books
    if set(book['title'].lower().split()).intersection(words)
       or set(book['description'].lower().split()).intersection(words)
])
```

---

```
# using regex

import re

words = re.compile("|".join(words), re.IGNORECASE)

# 11 µs ± 874 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
print([
    book for book in books
    if words.findall(book['title'])
       or words.findall(book['description'])
])
```